# why google lens can't recognise QR made by pyqrcode on an image made by using PIL library?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, qr-code

I am working on a template kind of thing where the input are some images and text while the result being an image.
Here one of the input is a QR code generated using `pyqrcode`. I am using `PIL` library to paste images and text. Problem here is google lens is not recognizing the qr code.
What to do to solve this issue.

[image: Example of the image is]

The code I written to generate image

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw
import pyqrcode
#Read the two images
image1 = Image.open('./10.jpg')
#image1.show()
image2 = Image.open('./2.jpg')
#image2.show()
#resize, first image,second image
image1 = image1.resize((320,640))
image2=image2.resize((144,144))
image1_size = image1.size
image2_size = image2.size
#pasting image2 on image1
image1.paste(image2,(100,220))



#Adding text
font1=ImageFont.truetype('./1.ttf',30)
font2=ImageFont.truetype('./1.ttf',20)
text1="My Home Jewels"
image3=ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
image3.text((30,30),text1,(237,230,211),font=font1)


#Adding QR code
link1="www.google.com"
url=pyqrcode.QRCode(link1,error='L')
url.png('test.png',scale=2)
img=Image.open('test.png') 
#img.save('./qr.jpg',quality=100)
#img=img.resize((72,72))
image1.paste(img,(30,500))

#Adding link as text
image3=ImageDraw.Draw(image1)
image3.text((120,520),link1,(237,230,211),font=font2)
image1.show()
image1.save('./3.jpg',quality=100)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding the `http://` prefix to `www.google.com`?

Comment: Yes, it's not working. Problem is lens is not recognizing the qr code itself, when I just give qr code without the actual image it's working

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce. This image works for me.